# Unrecognized disk label using hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, raid

I have a old hard drive that I am trying to use. I don't remember if it was used in a RAID with lvm or zfs or another format.

When I boot in Windows 10, I can see it under disks and it loads with no errors (the first time it did ask me to update the mbr) and it works well.

Under linux using ubuntu live cd is another story. I tried :

- Gparted: can't create a partition and have the error *unrecognized disk label*
- `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M`, no result
  [this solution][1], no result
- used parted: https://serverfault.com/questions/104923/unrecognised-disc-label-when-using-parted-with-qemu-images, no result

Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bios configuration. It was a mix of AVAHI and IDE. Switching everything to either AVAHI or IDE solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, launch [diskpart](https://ss64.com/nt/diskpart.html), and identify all the disks in your Windows filesystem with `list disk`

Select the disk in question with  `sel disk 2` (change the number to match the number of the drive in question) then do `list part` and `list vol`. Anything there you need to save?

Once you are satisfied you can proceed, do `clean` and your disk will be ready for reuse with *gparted*.

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux the combination of the `blkid` and the `wipefs` commands will do what you need:

- `blkid` will tell you, what the kernel sees on that disk
- `wipefs` will allow you to remove anything that is in the way

Refer to the man pages for details, but start at `blkid /dev/sdX` and `wipefs -a /dev/sdX`. As usual: Be sure you work on the correct disk!